# Can execution of CUDA kernels from two contexts overlap?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

From [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-kernel-execution), it appears that two kernels from different contexts cannot execute concurrently. In this regard, I am confused when reading CUPTI activity traces from two applications. The traces show kernel_start_timestamp, kernel_end_timestamp and duration (which is kernel_end_timestamp - kernel_start_timestamp).

Application 1:
.......
8024328958006530 8024329019421612 61415082
.......

Application 2:
.......
8024328940410543 8024329048839742 108429199

To make the long timestamp and duration more readable:

Application 1 : kernel X of 61.415 ms ran from xxxxx28.958 s to xxxxx29.019 s

Application 2 : kernel Y of 108.429 ms ran from xxxxx28.940 s to xxxxx29.0488 s

So, the execution of kernel X completely overlaps with that of kernel Y.

I am using the /path_to_cuda_install/extras/CUPTI/sample/activity_trace_async for tracing the applications. I modified CUPTI_ACTIVITY_ATTR_DEVICE_BUFFER_SIZE to 1024 and CUPTI_ACTIVITY_ATTR_DEVICE_BUFFER_POOL_LIMIT to 1. I have only enabled tracing for CUPTI_ACTIVITY_KIND_MEMCPY, CUPTI_ACTIVITY_KIND_CONCURRENT_KERNEL and CUPTI_ACTIVITY_KIND_OVERHEAD. My applications are calling cuptiActivityFlushAll(0) once in each of their respective logical timesteps.

Are these erroneous CUPTI values that I am seeing due to improper usage or is it something else?

Clarification : MPS not enabled, running on single GPU

UPDATE: [bug](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvbugs/cuda/edit/1661629) filed, this seems to be a known problem for CUDA 6.5
Waiting for a chance to test this with CUDA 7 (have a GPU shared between multiple users and need a window of inactivity for temporary switch to CUDA 7)

Comment: I recommend you file a bug report with NVIDIA registered developer program. Please include a reproducible, OS, driver version, and GPU information. The only cases where this can occur is (a) MPS, (b) Linux/MacOS with thread block level pre-emption (CC >= 3.5), and (c) the  kernels ran on two different GPUs. The timestamps are closer together than I would expect for (b) to have occurred.

Comment: @GregSmith By (b), did you mean preemption of a CDP kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I don't no how to set the CUPTI activity traces. But, 2 kernels can share a time-span on a single GPU even without the MPS server, though only one will run on the GPU at a time.

If CUDA MPS Server is not in use, then kernels from different contexts cannot overlap. I am assuming that you're not using the MPS server, then time-sliced scheduler will decide which context to access the GPU at a time. without MPS a context can only access the GPU in a time-slots that the time-sliced scheduler assigns to it. Thus, there are only kernels from a single context running on a GPU at a time (without the MPS server).

Note that, it is potentially possible that multiple kernels sharing a time-span with each other on a GPU, but still in that time-span only a kernels from a single context can access the GPU resources (which I am also assuming that you're using a single GPU).

For more information you can also check the [MPS Service](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf) document

Comment: I have updated the OP. Both of your assumptions are correct.

Comment: "Note that, it is potentially possible that multiple kernels sharing a time-span with each other on a GPU, but still in that time-span only a kernels from a single context can access the GPU resources " Can you explain this in more detail? It seems to me that is only possible if a kernel is interrupted and later resumed (context switch). I thought context switches are only possible at kernel boundaries.